# Remover elementos repetido dentro de um array em JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Como fazer para remover elementos repetidos dentro de um array em JavaScript?

Eu tenho por exemplo:

```
var array = ['foo', 'bar', 'foo'];
```

E quero remover todos os duplicados para obter:

```
['foo', 'bar']
```

Comment: Você conseguiu resolver sua resposta?

Answer (score 43):

Pode usar assim:

```
var arr = ['foo', 'bar', 'foo'];
var novaArr = arr.filter(function(este, i) {
    return arr.indexOf(este) === i;
});
console.log(novaArr); //dá ['foo', 'bar']
```

Em versão curta seria:

```
var arr = ['foo', 'bar', 'foo'];
var novaArr = arr.filter((este, i) => arr.indexOf(este) === i);
console.log(novaArr); //dá ['foo', 'bar']
```

O que este código faz é usar o [.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Nessa função nativa só passam os elementos que derem `return` com valor boleano `true`. E o que a funçõ verifica é se a posição de cada elemento dentro da array é  mesma que o indice que a função passa.

Ou seja `arr.indexOf(este)` dá a posição/index deste elemento na array, e a variàvel `i` que a função passa faz o mesmo. Se forem iguais então esse elemento é "original" ou seja, é a primeira vez que ele aparece. No caso de um duplicado, o valor do `i` vai corresponder à posição do duplicado, mas o `arr.indexOf(este)` vai dar a posição da primeira vez que esse valor aparece na array.

Esta função é +/- recente e o Internet Explorer só suporta a partir da versão 9. No link que coloquei em cima existe uma alternativa para o IE8. Infelismente o IE7 é demasiado velhino e como não tem prototype essa solução não se aplica.

Comment: É bom registrar que `filter` é IE9+, mas tem um *polyfill* na documentação linkada na resposta.

Comment: @bfavaretto verdade. Acrescentei info sobre isso. Obrigado!

Comment: Acho que vale mencionar que, como a complexidade dessa função é O(n^2), pode degradar em performance conforme o número de elementos cresce.

Answer (score 13):

Pode utilizar o `Set`, introduzido no ECMAScript 2015 (ES6):

```
const arr = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, "teste", "teste"];
const arrUnique = [...new Set(arr)];
```

Não tente utilizar esse meio para remover objetos duplicados, uma vez que estes são comparados por referência.

Fontes para uma pesquisa mais aprofundada:

- [Documentação do `Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)
- [Suporte entre navegadores](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_set)
- [Tabela comparativa](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/)

Comment: Wow, that is so cool!

Comment: Essa foi a resposta com a solução mais elegante. Obrigado.

Answer (score 8):

Para fazer com JavaScript puro, conforme respondido nesse link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9229821

```
uniqueArray = myArray.filter(function(elem, pos, self) {
    return self.indexOf(elem) == pos;
})
```

Answer (score 8):

```
a = ["Mike","Matt","Nancy","Adam","Jenny","Nancy","Carl"];
b = {};
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    b[a[i]] = a[i];
}
arr = [];
for (var key in b) {
    arr.push(key);
}
```

Trata-se de um dicionário de dados que quando a chave já existe o valor é simplesmente sobrescrito e, assim, evitando a redundância, pois a chave é sempre única em dicionários de dados.Depois o array é preenchido com os valores contidos no dicionário antes preenchido.

> **Fonte**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9229784

Comment: Explique o que o código está fazendo, e no caso de ter copiado o mesmo de outro lugar, ao menos [cite a fonte](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9229784/694105).

Comment: Na minha opinião, ele ajudou, e tenhamos mais paciência com aqueles que adentraram agora o SOPT ...

Comment: @Venatci, foi muito útil sua resposta mostrou uma maneira trivial, por favor se tiver a fonte colocar e creditar, para que enriqueça a sua resposta, e não tenho pontos negativos

Comment: Localizei a fonte e inseri, mas acho que uma explicação de como funciona deixaria a resposta mais completa. Não quer adicionar?

Comment: E se o array for de inteiros? Penso que esta técnica não funciona.

Answer (score 3):

A maneira mais performática é converter o vetor em um dicionário, e depois converter para vetor novamente.

```
function Foo (vetor) {
    var dicionario = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < vetor.length; i++) {
        dicionario[vetor[i] + ""] = true;
    }
    var novoVetor = [];
    for (var chave in dicionario) {
        novoVetor.push(chave);
    }
    return novoVetor;
}
```

Essa técnica evita que se perca tempo com buscas no vetor. Você simplesmente escreve cada valor no dicionário - e se um determinado valor se repetir `n` vezes, ele será sobrescrito `n - 1` vezes.

Note que o valor `true` nas chaves do dicionário é apenas um valor arbitrário. Poderia ser `0`, `1`, e acredito que na maioria dos casos até mesmo `null` irá funcionar, já que vamos ignorar esse valor e nos importar apenas com a chave ;)

**Edição:** acabo de ver que minha resposta é só uma versão mais verborrágica da resposta do Venatci. Kudos para ele.

Answer (score 2):

Acho que vale deixar uma [terceira alternativa](https://github.com/kvz/phpjs/blob/master/functions/array/array_unique.js), parte do projeto [PHPJS](http://www.phpjs.org) que visa trazer para o JS recursos presentes no PHP. Nesse caso, um *port* da função [array_unique()](http://www.php.net/array_unique):

```
function array_unique(inputArr) {
  //  discuss at: http://phpjs.org/functions/array_unique/
  // original by: Carlos R. L. Rodrigues (http://www.jsfromhell.com)
  //    input by: duncan
  //    input by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
  // bugfixed by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
  // bugfixed by: Nate
  // bugfixed by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
  // bugfixed by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
  // improved by: Michael Grier
  //        note: The second argument, sort_flags is not implemented;
  //        note: also should be sorted (asort?) first according to docs
  //   example 1: array_unique(['Kevin','Kevin','van','Zonneveld','Kevin']);
  //   returns 1: {0: 'Kevin', 2: 'van', 3: 'Zonneveld'}
  //   example 2: array_unique({'a': 'green', 0: 'red', 'b': 'green', 1: 'blue', 2: 'red'});
  //   returns 2: {a: 'green', 0: 'red', 1: 'blue'}

  var key = '',
    tmp_arr2 = {},
    val = '';

  var __array_search = function (needle, haystack) {
    var fkey = '';
    for (fkey in haystack) {
      if (haystack.hasOwnProperty(fkey)) {
        if ((haystack[fkey] + '') === (needle + '')) {
          return fkey;
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  };

  for (key in inputArr) {
    if (inputArr.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      val = inputArr[key];
      if (false === __array_search(val, tmp_arr2)) {
        tmp_arr2[key] = val;
      }
    }
  }

  return tmp_arr2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Não tenho muita expriência com programação e rencentemente comecei a migrar do Java para o JS e com isso acho que eu trouxe a herança maldita da verbosidade no código, não tenho noção da performance desse algoritmo abaixo, mas funcionou pra resolver um exercício aqui.

```
function limpaValoresRepetidos(array){
    for(let i in array){ 
        let valorComparado = array[i]    
        let cont = 0         //contador de incidencia de repeticao, seu valor deve ser 1
        for(let i in array){
            if(valorComparado === array[i]){
                cont +=1
                if(cont > 1){
                    cont --
                    delete array[i]
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return array
}
```