# Como obter valores únicos em um array JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, array

Em PHP, quando possuo um `array` com valores duplicados, é possível obter apenas valores únicos através da função `array_unique`.

Exemplo:

```
$array = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c'];

array_unique($array); // ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Porém eu precisei fazer algo parecido em JavaScript, mas não encontrei uma função que fizesse isso nativamente.

Qual é o meio mais simples em JavaScript de se obter os valores únicos de um `array`?

Vou deixar esse *array* de exemplo:

```js
var array = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c'];

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Mais respostas [nesta duplicada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16483/69296).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

A solução que pode ser adotada agora em JS (a não ser que precise funcionar com versões antigas) é muito mais simples e melhor:

```js
var array = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c'];
var unique = [...new Set(array)];
console.log(unique);
```

Note que isso só funciona bem porque tudo é *string*, com valores diferentes pode não sair como espera.

Se precisar usar uma outra solução e esperar um *array* mais grandinho será mais interessante fazer um um *set* como se fosse um objeto, ou seja, usar os valores como chaves, assim não haverá repetição e manterá uma performance boa, mas um pouco pior. Algo assim:

```js
var array = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c'];
var unique = array.reduce((acc, curr) => (acc[curr] = '', acc), {});
console.log(Object.keys(unique));
```

A solução abaixo era a mais fácil na época, mas tem o problema relatado pelo Luiz Felipe em comentário, então não costuma ser uma boa idea.

---

A solução que mais gosto é criar uma função para usar junto com [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) que é usado justamente para determinar quais elementos devem ser considerados em uma avaliação. Ela usa um estilo funcional de programação onde interessa o que faz e não como faz.

```js
function unique(value, index, self) { 
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}

var array = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c'];
var unique = array.filter(unique);
console.log(unique);
```

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14438954/221800).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Array/UniqueValues.js).

`filter()` é uma função que varre todos elementos do *array* e manda para uma função de *callback* definida pelo programador. Nessa função faz uma comparação se é a primeira ocorrência do valor e só se for é que a `filter()` irá considerar como parte do novo *array*.

O [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) dá a posição da primeira ocorrência. Se ela bater com o índice atual do elemento pesquisado, é um valor que interessa no critério adotado. Se não bater significa que já é pelo menos uma segunda ocorrência desse valor, o que não interessa.

Isso deve funcionar na maioria dos navegadores usados atualmente, só não funciona nos que já são considerados muito antigos.

Comment: Sucinto, eficiente e fácil de se interpretar +1. :D

Comment: Tem um problema no algoritmo, por conta do `indexOf` se você passar `[NaN]` o valor `NaN` é perdido no filtro, já que o `indexOf` possui um problema onde `NaN` retorna sempre -1.

Comment: @GabrielKatakura é, pode ter esse problema que precisa ser tratado. Pode ser que tenha outros, em JS não é fácil fechar todos casos sem tratar um monte de exceção. Acredito que é uma boa ressalva para todos os algoritmos postados que usam técnica semelhante ou que possui suas próprias deficiências.

Comment: @bigown 90% dos algoritmos que eu vejo de uma implementação `unique` possuem esse problema no JS, isso é normal, já que o próprio `indexOf` cai na clássica pegadinha do `NaN !== NaN`

Comment: Acho que vale a pena salientar que, como tanto `filter` quanto `indexOf` são lineares, esse código é executada em tempo quadrático, o que _não_ é eficiente para casos em que o número de elementos já começa a ficar expressivo. [A diferença chega a ser gritante.](https://jsbench.me/47kp7cbl4k/1)

Comment: @LuizFelipe deu uma melhorada.

Comment: Boa! Vou aproveitar e linkar [esta outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/510118), q discute, de modo mais profundo, sobre como o `Set` funciona p/ remover duplicados. E só um outro detalhe, no segundo cód., os elms. serão convertidos p/ string p/ se adequar ao tipo (`string`) esperado pelas chaves do objeto ([ver aqui](https://git.io/JGOox)). Por conta disso, objetos também deixam de ser comparados por ref., mas sim pelo resultado de seu `toString`. Talvez, nesse caso, seja melhor usar um [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

Comment: @LuizFelipe acho que tem razão, vou fazer uns testes.

Answer (score 23):

Aqui ficam 4 variantes:

```
const array = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c'];
```

#### usando JavaScript do futuro

```
const unique = [...new Set(array)];
```

Como o [@stderr](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/6454/stderr) referiu [na resposta dele](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/150425/129) já estão planeados (ainda não lançados oficialmente) dois conceitos que podem ser usados para o fim da pergunta. Um deles o [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), que é uma maneira nova de organizar iteráveis. O outro é [a sintaxe spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) que permite representar/converter iteráveis, mais ou menos como uma indicação para escrever o objeto "por extenso". Neste caso combinando os dois, dá o que se pede na pergunta.

Esta solução resolve ainda [o problema que o Gabriel referiu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/150413/como-obter-valores-%C3%BAnicos-em-um-array-javascript/150417#comment310634_150415) e que existe na solução com `.filter()`. (exemplo: http://www.es6fiddle.net/iskjh2q8/)

#### Usando `.filter`:

```
const unique = array.filter((el, i, arr) => arr.indexOf(el) == i);
console.log(unique); // ["a", "b", "c"]
```

O método `.filter` está disponivel nativamente para arrays e aceita uma função (callback). Essa função recebe 3 argumentos: o elemento a ser iterado, o index (posição) que está a ser iterada, e a array original. Usando `arr.indexOf(el) == i` garantimos que apenas a primeira vez que cada duplicado aparece resolve como `true`, limpando assim os outros elementos.

#### Usando `.reduce` e um verificador ternário.

```
const unique = array.reduce(
    (arr, el) => arr.concat(arr.includes(el) ? [] : [el]), []
);
console.log(unique); // ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Neste caso com o `.reduce` podemos ir juntando elementos a uma array inicializada no segundo argumento do método `reduce`. Ele itera todas as posições da array e com o ternário verificamos se o elemento já existe na nova array que está a ser criada dentro do reduce.

#### Usando um objeto para evitar duplicar chaves

(só util quando usamos *Primitivos*)

```
const unique = ((obj, arr) => {
    arr.forEach(el => obj[el] = true);
    return Object.keys(obj);
})({}, array);
console.log(unique); // ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Neste caso vamos populando um objeto com chaves formadas pelos elementos da array inicial. Uma vez que objetos só permitem chaves únicas, quando a iteração estiver completa podemos retornar `Object.keys(obj)` que dá uma nova array com essas chaves únicas.

Comment: Ecma 6  puro :D!

Comment: Boa resposta (+1)

Answer (score 16):

### ES6+

A partir do ES6 também pode-se usar o [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

> The `Set` object lets you store unique values of any type, whether
>   primitive values or object references.

Veja um exemplo:

```js
var valores = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 1, 2, 2, 3];

var unique = new Set(valores);

alert([...unique]);
```

Comment: `Set` e `spread`... `+1`

Comment: Boa indicação do Set (+1)

Comment: Tiraste essa de python :P

Comment: julia também usa sets, qualquer linguagem que leva ao pó da letra a definição de conjuntos vai ter.

Answer (score 8):

Utilizando `array.filter`

```js
function array_unique(array){
    return array.filter(function(el, index, arr) {
        return index == arr.indexOf(el);
    });
}

var array = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c'];

console.log('Array original:');
console.log( array);
console.log('Array após utilização de array_unique:');
console.log( array_unique(array));
```

Comment: Acho que vale a pena salientar que, como tanto `filter` quanto `indexOf` são lineares, esse código é executada em tempo quadrático, o que _não_ é eficiente para casos em que o número de elementos já começa a ficar expressivo. [A diferença chega a ser gritante.](https://jsbench.me/47kp7cbl4k/1)

Answer (score 5):

Bem simples, percorre o array e vai colocando os items em um array temporario, e verifica se o item existe ou não no array temporario.

```js
function array_unique(array){
 var unique = [];
 for(var i in array){
  if(unique.indexOf(array[i])==-1){
   unique.push(array[i]);
  }
 }
 
 return unique;
}

var array = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c'];
console.log(array_unique(array));
```

Answer (score 4):

Outra solução seria.

```
Array.prototype.getUnique = function(){
   var u = {}, a = [];
   for(var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; ++i){
      if(u.hasOwnProperty(this[i])) {
         continue;
      }
      a.push(this[i]);
      u[this[i]] = 1;
   }
   return a;
}

var array = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c'];
array.getUnique();
```

Fonte: [SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/unique-values-in-an-array/1961068#1961068)