# Como remover valores duplicados de um array multidimensional no javascript?

Tags: javascript, estrutura-de-dados

Boa noite,

Preciso remover os resultados duplicados em um array com outros arrays aninhados.

Eu tenho a seguinte variável:

```
 var dados = [
  ['maria', 'telefone', '324-5678', true],
  ['maria', 'telefone', '91234-5555', true],
  ['maria', 'telefone', '324-5678', false],
  ['jonas', 'telefone', '98888-1111', true],
  ['jonas', 'telefone', '56789-1010', true],
];
```

Onde todos os registros de mesmo nome e com o mesmo valor de telefone devem ser removidos.

Nesse caso, o valor a ser retornado deveria ser:

```
 var dados = [
  ['maria', 'telefone', '91234-5555', true],
  ['maria', 'telefone', '324-5678', false],
  ['jonas', 'telefone', '98888-1111', true],
  ['jonas', 'telefone', '56789-1010', true],
];
```

Tentei usar o set, mas ele só remove valores duplicados se todos os valores estiverem em um único array.

Agradeço a atenção

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O método semântico a usar é o `.filter` para filtrar a array principal e o `.some` para verificar se há cópias. A vantagem em usar o `.some` é ser um iterador que pára quando encontrar um caso que dê `true`, poupando o processamento do resto da array.

Tens de comparar, como indicaste, que o nome e o telefone são iguais.

Podes fazer isso assim:

```js
var dados = [
  ['maria', 'telefone', '324-5678', true],
  ['maria', 'telefone', '91234-5555', true],
  ['maria', 'telefone', '324-5678', false],
  ['jonas', 'telefone', '98888-1111', true],
  ['jonas', 'telefone', '56789-1010', true],
];

var filtrados = dados.filter(([nome, _, telefone], i) => {
  return !dados.some(
    ([_nome, __, _telefone], j) => j > i && nome === _nome && telefone === _telefone
  );
});

console.log(filtrados);
```

Comment: Obrigada @Sergio, funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode utilizar o método [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro) e fazer a verificação.

```js
var dados = [
  ['maria', 'telefone', '324-5678', true],
  ['maria', 'telefone', '91234-5555', true],
  ['maria', 'telefone', '324-5678', false],
  ['jonas', 'telefone', '98888-1111', true],
  ['jonas', 'telefone', '56789-1010', true],
];

dados = dados.filter((item, pos, array) => {
  return array.map(x => x[2]).indexOf(item[2]) === pos;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(dados));
```

`x[2]` e `item[2]` é o índice do telefone no array.

#### Referências

- [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro)
- [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Como obter valores únicos em um array JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/150413)

Answer (score 2):

Você pode percorrer o array e para cada posição percorrer o mesmo novamente verificando a duplicidade. Caso não encontre duplicidade adicione o valor em um novo array.

```js
var dados = [
  ['maria', 'telefone', '324-5678', true],
  ['maria', 'telefone', '91234-5555', true],
  ['maria', 'telefone', '324-5678', false],
  ['jonas', 'telefone', '98888-1111', true],
  ['jonas', 'telefone', '56789-1010', true],
];

var novaLista = [];

dados.forEach(function(item1, x) {
  var duplicado = false;
  dados.forEach(function(item2, y) {
    if (x < y) {
      if (item1[0] == item2[0] && item1[2] == item2[2]) {
        duplicado = true;
        return false;
      }
    }
  });

  if (!duplicado) {
    novaLista.push(item1);
  }
});

console.log(novaLista);
```