# Como remover valores duplicados de um array de objetos facilmente?

Tags: javascript

Tenho o seguinte array:

```
[  
   {  
      "value":"ETH",
      "label":"ETH"
   },
   {  
      "value":"LTC",
      "label":"LTC"
   },
   {
      "value":"ETH",
      "label":"ETH"
   }
]
```

Como da pra ver, existem valores duplicados. Qual a melhor forma para retira-los?

Já tentei fazer dessas 2 formas, mas sem sucesso:

```js
let values = [  
   {  
      "value":"ETH",
      "label":"ETH"
   },
   {  
      "value":"LTC",
      "label":"LTC"
   },
   {
      "value":"ETH",
      "label":"ETH"
   }
]

console.log(values.filter((elem, index, self) => index === self.indexOf(elem)))

console.log([... new Set(values)])
```

Não entendi o porque do set não ter funcionado, já que ele tenta criar uma lista só de valores unicos.

Comment: da uma olhada aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16483/remover-elementos-repetido-dentro-de-um-vetor-em-javascript

Comment: @WeesSmith A resposta dessa pergunta(como ela mesmo indica) não funciona para um vetor de objetos.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Uma forma simples de remover as duplicatas é assim:

```js
let values = [  
   {  
      "value":"ETH",
      "label":"ETH"
   },
   {  
      "value":"LTC",
      "label":"LTC"
   },
   {
      "value":"ETH",
      "label":"ETH"
   }
]

values = values.filter(function (a) {
 return !this[JSON.stringify(a)] && (this[JSON.stringify(a)] = true);
}, Object.create(null))

console.log(values)
```

**Explicação:**

Basicamente o que ele faz é iterar sobre os objetos do array e adicionar o seu valor serializado ao objeto temporário criado no 2º argumento como uma chave, e assim indicar se ele já foi adicionado colocando-o o valor `true`. Assim, quando chega um valor duplicado, a condicional `!this[JSON.stringify(a)]` da `false`, não adicionando-o ao filtro.

Teoricamente, se 2 objetos são iguais, eles serializados possuem o mesmo valor.

**Por que o Set não funcionou?**

O Set compara o endereço dos objetos por padrão, veja um exemplo:

```js
  let set = new Set()
  let a = {}, b = {}, c = {}
  set.add(a)
  set.add(b)
  set.add(b)
  console.log(set.size)
  console.log(set.has(a))
  console.log(set.has(b))
  console.log(set.has(c))
```

Comment: O problema da resposta é que ela verifica apenas uma chave (value)... se a outra chave (label) for diferente, ela remove do mesmo jeito.

Comment: @dvd Verdade. Modifiquei a resposta para adequar-se.

Comment: Uma dúvida.... eu estava usando a sua solução de remover duplicatas em caso de uso meu. Só que surgiu um problema.
Coloquei o código abaixo em uma função é chamada toda vez que o valor do campo select é alterado.

values = values.filter(function (a) {
 return !this[JSON.stringify(a)] && (this[JSON.stringify(a)] = true);
}, Object.create(null))

Só que quando eu seleciono, por exemplo, "A" e depois "B" corre tudo bem. Os valores duplicados são removidos, mas se eu volto para "A" o array retornado é vazio.

Como eu resolvo isso para não trazer o array vazio e sim sem os valores repetido

Comment: @Leonardo não entendi direito. Acho q o ideal é criar uma pergunta para esse problema em especifico. Se fizer, manda o link aq q eu tento ajudar.

Answer (score 3):

```
var original = [{a:1}, {a:1}, {a:2}, {a:3}, {a:1}, {a:2}, {a:5}];
var reduced = [];

original.forEach((item) => {
    var duplicated  = reduced.findIndex(redItem => {
        return item.a == redItem.a;
    }) > -1;

    if(!duplicated) {
        reduced.push(item);
    }
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(reduced));
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
let values = [  
  {  
     "value":"ETH",
     "label":"ETH"
  },
  {  
     "value":"LTC",
     "label":"LTC"
  },
  {
     "value":"ETH",
     "label":"ETH"
  }
]

const parsed_array = values.map(val=>{return JSON.stringify(val)})
const filtered_array= parsed_array.filter((value, ind)=> parsed_array.indexOf(value) == ind).map((val)=>{return JSON.parse(val)})
console.log(filtered_array)
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).