# Restful API com NodeJS e Mysql com Multiplas Colunas (quero retornar json em níveis)

Tags: node.js, api

tudo bem. Alguém pode me ajudar com uma questão de Angular, ou da API com Node.js?

Eu consulto Mysql numa api com Node.js com inner join em 2 tabelas, mas como é de se esperar o mysql me retorna tudo numa única array, mas acho mais correto e viável retornar as arrays em nível.

Exemplo retornando os results direto do mysql:

```
[
    {
        coluna1: 'AAAAA',
        coluna2: 'XXXXX'
    },{
        coluna1: 'AAAAA',
        coluna2: 'YYYYY'
    },{
        coluna1: 'BBBBB',
        coluna2: 'ZZZZZ'
    },
]
```

O que eu quero é transformar nisso:

```
[
    {
        coluna1: 'AAAAA',
        outra_arary: [
            {
                coluna2:  'XXXXX'
            },{
                coluna2:  'YYYYY'
            }
        ]
    },{
        coluna1: 'BBBBB',
        outra_arary: [
            {
                coluna2:  'ZZZZZ'
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Um exemplo de como é o método:

```
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.connection.query(`select *
                                   from tabela1
                             inner join tabela2
                                on tabela1.id = tabela2.id;`, (error, results, fields) => {
        if (error) {
            res.send({
                "status" : 500,
                "error" : error,
                "response" : null
            });
        } else {
            res.send({
                "status" : 200,
                "error" : null,
                "response" : results
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma ideia é utilizar:

```js
// Exemplo de resposta do MYSQL
const resultados = [
  {
      coluna1: 'AAAAA',
      coluna2: 'XXXXX'
  },{
      coluna1: 'AAAAA',
      coluna2: 'YYYYY'
  },{
      coluna1: 'BBBBB',
      coluna2: 'ZZZZZ'
  },
]

// Função que retorna o array "outra_array", que contém vários objetos com os dados de coluna2
function retornaColuna(coluna) {
  const colunaFiltrada = new Array()
  resultados.forEach(valor => {
    if(valor.coluna1 == coluna)
      colunaFiltrada.push({ coluna2: valor.coluna2 })
  })
  return colunaFiltrada
}

// Itera sobre o array de resposta do MYSQL, criando a estrutura desejada. Nesse caso, coluna1 pode estar repetido.
let resposta = new Array()
resultados.forEach(valor => {
  resposta.push({ coluna1: valor.coluna1, outra_array: retornaColuna(valor.coluna1) })
})

// Remove as colunas1 duplicadas.
resposta = resposta.filter((a) => !this[JSON.stringify(a)] && (this[JSON.stringify(a)] = true))

console.log(resposta) // Retornará o resultado esperado
```

A última função, que retira possíveis objetos duplicados no Array, está disponível [aqui no Stack](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/296660/como-remover-valores-duplicados-de-um-array-de-objetos-facilmente)

Comment: Obrigado João Pedro, não entendi muito a ideia mas vou tentar fazer o teste e coloco a resposta aqui. Sou novo com node.js. Até hoje ainda apanho um pouco pra entender esses conceitos.

Comment: Consegui João Pedro, entendi a lógica também, foi super simples. Muito bom, muito obrigado.

Comment: João, agora quando executo 2 vezes seguidas, ele retorna minha array nula, como se estivesse guardando cache, as vezes retorna 304

Comment: O código ou a request?

Comment: Era o request que estava fazendo na API, mas aí descobri que faltava algo ali naquela última linha onde removemos os duplicados, percebi isso comparando a diferença do seu código aqui com o [link que você mencionou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/296660/como-remover-valores-duplicados-de-um-array-de-objetos-facilmente)

Corrigido ficou assim:

`retornoFinal = retornoFinal.filter(function (a) {
                return !this[JSON.stringify(a)] && (this[JSON.stringify(a)] = true);
            }, Object.create(null));`

Agora deu certo!! Muito obrigado!

Comment: Bem notado. Fico feliz que deu tudo certo ;D