# Não aceitar valores duplicados em uma Expressão Regular (Regex)

Tags: javascript, regex

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
var str = "141271999 243306211 172266710 172266710 172266710";
var regex =  /[0-9]{9}/g; //Encontrar 9 números entre 0-9 e retornar todos valores (g).
var idsEncontrados = str.match(regex);
```

Como posso configurar minha regex para desconsiderar os valores duplicados encontrados fazendo com que minha variável `idsEncontrados` receba somente os valores `141271999, 243306211, 172266710`?

Comment: Não é mais fácil [implementar essa lógica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16483/5878) filtrando os repetidos em `idsEncontrados`?

Comment: é uma possibilidade...mas imagino que talvez possa existir alguma flag ou coisa parecida para configurar a regex desta maneira.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode utilizar a seguinte regex:

```
([0-9]{9})(?!.*\1)
```

[Veja a funcionar no regex101](https://regex101.com/r/z7c0qL/1)

Explicação:

```
(        - primeiro grupo de captura
[0-9]{9} - 9 digitos de 0 a 9
)        - fecha o grupo de captura
(?!      - Negative lookahead, que não tenha à frente
.*       - qualquer coisa
\1)      - seguida do que foi capturado no grupo 1
```

Exemplo no código:

```js
var str = "141271999 243306211 172266710 172266710 172266710";
var regex =  /([0-9]{9})(?!.*\1)/g;
var idsEncontrados = str.match(regex);

console.log(idsEncontrados);
```

No entanto, assim como o @AndersonCarlosWoss mencionou, é uma lógica fácil de implementar diretamente em Javascript, utilizando a função `filter`.

Veja a pergunta relacionada: [Remover elementos repetido dentro de um vetor em javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16483/remover-elementos-repetido-dentro-de-um-vetor-em-javascript)

Comment: Obrigado @Isac! Sua solução da expressão regular funcionou perfeitamente. Eu acredito que seja mais fácil utilizar a expressão regular, apesar que a sugestão do @AndersonCarlosWoss também é uma ótima alternativa.